# How to change Jasper Reports language?

Tags: oracle, jasperserver

I'm using Jaspersoft server to print some PDF files.

The server is connected to an Oracle Database through oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver.

It's configured as follows :

[image]

The server is working nicely. However when running a report that has a query like :

```
select to_char('Month', sysdate) from dual;
```

The result is always in English.

Is it possible to change Jaspersoft server connection to Oracle and make it work in another language ?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/ntcli/configuring-locale-and-character-sets-using-nls-lang-environment-variable.html#GUID-100E7F17-656D-49B5-BC06-943A7278479D

Comment: @OldProgrammer thanks for the link. The question is where this code should be. As I don't have access to the part where Jasper server initialises the connection, I can't find where to set the language. When I'm creating the connection manually for a C# app or whatever, I set the language manually and it works. Here this stuff is done by Jasper and acts like a black box. Hence my question. Thanks though for the link.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT statement you posted is **invalid**. It won't work at all:

```
SQL> select to_char('Month', sysdate) from dual;
select to_char('Month', sysdate) from dual
               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

When fixed:

```
SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'Month') from dual;

TO_CHAR(
--------
Studeni
```

How to use another language (as result I previously got is in Croatian; let's try *English*):

```
SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'Month', 'nls_date_language = english') from dual;

TO_CHAR(S
---------
November

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The select statement is just an example I used for StackOverflow post. Instead of posting a huge query which is meaningless, I posted a small fictive query. As I said the reports print successfully. So there is no problem with the query in the real configuration. My issue is with the language.

Comment: You're welcome. So, does the NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE within the TO_CHAR function help?

Comment: yes this will work. But I was wondering if there is any way to set the language for the connection between Jasper and Oracle such that all dates will by default show in the correct language instead of changing all the query fields one by one. This will allow reusing the same queries in other apps and will show everytime in the correct language.